# tcolorbox : how to center multi lines text

Tags: tcolorbox, center

How to center multi lines text with `tcolorbox` ?

```
~\tcolorbox_helloworld> more .\helloworld.tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tcolorbox}[enhanced, colback=white, halign=center, valign=center, center]
    hello
    \newline
    world
  \end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

Gives me :

[image]

And using extra center environnement :

```
~\tcolorbox_helloworld> more .\helloworld.tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tcolorbox}[enhanced, colback=white, halign=center, valign=center, center]
    \begin{center}
      hello
      \newline
      world
    \end{center}
  \end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

Gives me :

[image]

Which is still not centered !

Answer (score 1):

Hope this will solve the issue:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tcolorbox}[enhanced, colback=white, halign=center, valign=center, center]
\centering
      hello

      world\par
  \end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: This does work too ! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tcolorbox}[enhanced, colback=white, halign=center, valign=center, center]
      hello\\
      world
  \end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It works !?... Thanks